# validation booking room outside range?

Tags: php, laravel

**#Code validation Booking**

```
  $request->validate([
        "start_date" => [
            "required",  
            function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request) {
                $booking = BookingTransaction::where('meeting_room_id', '=', $request->meeting_room_id)->where([
                    ["start_date", "<=", $request->input('start_date') . ' ' . $request->input('start_time')],
                    ["end_date", ">=", $request->input('start_date') . ' ' . $request->input('start_time')],
                ])
                ->orWhere([
                    ["meeting_room_id",'=',$request->meeting_room_id],
                    ["start_date", "<=", $request->input('start_date') . ' ' . $request->input('end_time')],
                    ["end_date", ">=", $request->input('start_date') . ' ' . $request->input('end_time')],
                ])
                ->first();
                if ($booking) {
                    $fail(
                        sprintf("Room meeting has already been booked. Please, try booking again outside this range.",
                            \Carbon\Carbon::create($booking->start_date)->format("d M Y H:i"),
                            \Carbon\Carbon::create($booking->end_date)->format("d M Y H:i")
                        )
                    );
                }
            },
        ],
    ]);
```

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-10 11:00:00 | 2022-10-10 15:00:00 |

**#problem**

The code above explains the validation if the user adds a booking schedule in the **time range between start_date : 2022-10-10 11:00:00 to end_date:
2022-10-10 15:00:00**, it will fail,
now I want to validate if the user makes a booking outside the **range between start_date:
2022-10-10 11:00:00
until
end_date:
2022-10-10 15:00:00**, it will fail,
for example:
if the user makes a booking **between:
start_date: 2022-10-10 09:00:00 to end_date: 2022-10-10 16:00:00 will fail** ,
how to do above validation ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this query.

```
$start = $request->input('start_date') . ' ' . $request->input('start_time');
$end = $request->input('start_date') . ' ' . $request->input('end_time'); 

$booking = BookingTransaction::where('meeting_room_id', '=', $request->meeting_room_id)
    ->where(function($query) use ($start, $end) {
        return $query->where(
                fn($q) => $q->where('start_date', '<=', $start)
                    ->where('end_date', '>=', $start)
            )
            ->orWhereBetween('start_date', [$start, $end])
            ->orWhereBetween('end_date', [$start, $end]);
    })
    ->exists()
```